# Простой парсер, не могу получить href из html (DOM)

Tags: delphi, dom

Всем привет. Помогите написать простенький парсер, не могу получить href в финале.
Выдергивает все что Li, потом внутри в h3, а потом в A.

```
    vTags := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementsByTagName('Li');
    n1:=vTags.Length;

    if n1>0 then
    begin

      for i1:=0 to n1-1 do
      begin
      vTags1 := vTags.item(i1).getElementsByTagName('H3');
      n2:=vTags1.Length;

        if n2>0 then
        begin

          for i2:=0 to n2-1 do
          begin
          sMemo2.Lines.Add(vTags1.item(i2).InnerHTML);
          end;

        end;

      end;

    end;
```

В sMemo2 получается:

```
     <A href="http://www.google.ru/url?url=http://www.elle.ru/tests/&amp;rct=j&amp;frm=1&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CBMQFjAAahUKEwj4n4380ZnHAhWI2SwKHdhEB2A&amp;usg=AFQjCNFKGc7G2o3Ta0OKGyFYhC8EjSKUHg" target=_blank><B>?????</B> ??????: ?????? ??????????????? <B>?????</B> ?????????, ??? <B>...</B></A>
```

Как получить href? Чето не пойму. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вместо

```
sMemo2.Lines.Add(vTags1.item(i2).InnerHTML);
```

использовать

```
sMemo2.Lines.Add(vTags1.item(i2).getAttribute(href,0));
```

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что это не регулярками, а специализированным HTML-парсером делается? Все еще не понимаю, почему минусы и почему вопрос закрывают.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, вопрос предлагаю закрыть, потому что реакции от автора вопроса ни какой и сам он пропал. P.S. Минусы не ставил.

Comment: а, понял. Ну да, если автора нет, то это norepro. Плюсанул ответ.